# Inconsistent return from same ajax call

Tags: php, jquery

Always return a blank page if submit page (test_page2.html) is called from menu page (test_menu.html). Normal return if directly call the submit page (test_page2.html)

Sorry to submit large content to there, content is as simply as I can.

Do anyone have same experience and know the whether this is a bug or somethings missed in my code? A live demo can be accessed from http://wh5.info/pub/test_menu.html

Content of testament.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <title>TEST</title> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <div data-role="page" id="createcamp">
        <div data-theme="b" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
          <h1 id="header" data-theme="e">Menu</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="cntrBlock">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                    <li data-role="list-divider">Menu</li>
                    <li><a href="test_page2.html">Goto Page 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
          <div data-theme="b" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
              <h1 id="footer">Copyright &copy; ABC</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Content of test_page2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <title>TEST</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(function () {
            $('#form1').submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
              $.ajax({
                cache: false, 
                type: "POST", 
                dataType: "json",
                            data: $('#form1').serialize(),
                url: $('#form1').attr('action'),
                complete: function (HttpRequest, textStatus) {
                    console.log(HttpRequest);
                    $obj = JSON.parse(HttpRequest.response);
                    $('#loginname').val($obj.login);
              }});
              return false;
            });
          });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="createcamp">
        <div data-theme="b" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
          <h1 id="header" data-theme="e">Submit Page</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <div class="campBlock">
                    <div id="message"></div>
                    <form action="test_php.php" method="POST" id="form1" name="form1">
                        <fieldset>
                            <label for="login" id="login_msg">Login</label>
                            <input type="text" name="loginname" id="loginname" />
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Content of test_php.php

```
<?php

$arr = array('login' => 'pass', 'message' => 'Well done!');

echo json_encode($arr);

?>
```

---

Comment: you can try $.getJSON( test_php.php?parameter="+parameter, function( data ){})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you go to your `test_page2.html` from `test_menu.html` it loads via ajax call, not the normal HTTP (I think it's jQuery mobile feature). Looks like only page body is loaded via this call so you don't have your form submit handler cause it's located inside the `head` tag.

If you go directly to `test_page2.html` in your browser it gets loaded via normal HTTP request with form submit handler `script` in the `head` tag.

More information about jQuery mobile navigation: http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/faq/scripts-and-styles-not-loading.html

So I suggest to:

1. Move the `script` tag with submit handler inside the `<div data-role="page"/>` so it can be loaded via jQuery mobile ajax navigation routine.
2. Use [pageinit](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/) event to attach the handler (instead of `$(document).ready`) as recommended by jQuery mobile docs.

Comment: Thanks vbo, I read the mobile navigation and solved the problem. As I don't have enough reputation, I could not able to answer my own question within 8 hours. I will post the final version here after 8 hours.

Comment: Edited: I've added some suggestions on how this can be fixed in your particular case.

Comment: Yes, I do the same as yours. Now I face another challenge. It is work in such simple coding.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I am newbie in using stackexchange. Thanks for reminder.

Answer (score 0):

your test_page2.html should be like below one.

remove head ,html and body tag from it

**Content of test_page2.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#form1').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                cache: false, 
                type: "POST", 
                dataType: "json",
                data: $('#form1').serialize(),
                url: $('#form1').attr('action'),
                complete: function (HttpRequest, textStatus) {
                    console.log(HttpRequest);
                    $obj = JSON.parse(HttpRequest.response);
                    $('#loginname').val($obj.login);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<div data-role="page" id="createcamp">
<div data-theme="b" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
  <h1 id="header" data-theme="e">Submit Page</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="campBlock">
            <div id="message"></div>
            <form action="test_php.php" method="POST" id="form1" name="form1">
                <fieldset>
                    <label for="login" id="login_msg">Login</label>
                    <input type="text" name="loginname" id="loginname" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no idea why need to remove all html, head and body as test_page2.html is an external html file but not part of test_menu.html.

Tried but still return a blank page.